Existence of smooth function with non vanishing gradient on a boundary.
Consider the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$A := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid | x | \leq \epsilon \text{ and } |y| \geq \epsilon \}.$$
The boundary is given by
$$\partial(A) = \{|x| = \epsilon \text{ and } |y| \geq \epsilon \} \, \bigcup \, \{ |x| \leq \epsilon \text{ and } | y | = \epsilon      \}.$$
My question is, does there exist a smooth function $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that the vanishing set equals $\partial A$ and $\nabla f \neq 0$ on $\partial A$? By vanishing set I mean $V(f) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid f(x,y) = 0\}$.
I tried the following. First, define  $b : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  by
$$
b(y) =
\begin{cases}
\exp\left(-\frac{\epsilon^2}{\epsilon^2 - y^2}\right), & |y| < \epsilon, \\
0, & |y| \geq \epsilon.
\end{cases}
$$
Next, define the function $a : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
a(x) =
\begin{cases} 
0, & \text{if } |x| \leq \epsilon, \\
\exp\left(-\frac{\epsilon^2}{x^2 - \epsilon^2}\right), & \text{if } |x| > \epsilon.
\end{cases}
$$
Now let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$f(x,y) := a(x) + b(y) + (x^2 - \epsilon^2)^2 (y^2 - \epsilon^2)^2.$$
We see that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =
\begin{cases} 
\exp\left(-\frac{1}{x^2 - \epsilon^2}\right) \cdot \frac{2x}{(x^2 - \epsilon^2)^2} + 4x(x^2 - \epsilon^2)(y^2 - \epsilon^2)^2 & \text{if } |x| > \epsilon, \\
4x(x^2 - \epsilon^2)(y^2 - \epsilon^2)^2 & \text{if } |x| \leq \epsilon,
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} =
\begin{cases} 
-\exp\left(-\frac{1}{\epsilon^2 - y^2}\right) \cdot \frac{2y}{(\epsilon^2 - y^2)^2} + 4y(y^2 - \epsilon^2)(x^2 - \epsilon^2)^2 & \text{if } |y| < \epsilon, \\
4y(y^2 - \epsilon^2)(x^2 - \epsilon^2)^2 & \text{if } |y| \geq \epsilon.
\end{cases}
$$
On the boundary of $A$, this reduces to
$$\nabla f|_{\partial A} = \left( 4x(x^2 - \epsilon^2)(y^2 - \epsilon^2)^2, 4y(y^2 - \epsilon^2)(x^2 - \epsilon^2)^2 \right), $$
and we see this is always zero because either $x$ or $y$ has absolute value $\epsilon$.
Perhaps this is not possible. If so, is there a general result explaining why?

Hint: Use the fact that ${(x,y): f(x,y)=0, \nabla f(x,y)\ne \mathbf 0}$ is a smooth 1-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

@MoisheKohan Thank you. After reading your comment, I believe that if such a function $f$ did exist, it would violate the implicit function theorem/regular value theorem. Is this what you were getting at? If so, my updated question is as follows. Suppose we just considered the ray ${ x = \epsilon, y \geq \epsilon}$. Is there any way to write this as a vanishing set of a function $f$ as differentiable as possible (but perhaps not smooth) with non-vanishing gradient on this ray?

The result about submanifolds is equivalent to the implicit function theorem. As for your modification, it is equally impossible, for the same reason.
